# Deeply equal function error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function to check whether two arrays are deeply equal to each other.
An example would be: `[1, 2, { a: "hello" }]` and `[1, 2, { a: "bye" }]` would return false.

This is my code so far:

```
const deeplyEquals = (val1, val2) => {
  let counter = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < val1.length; i++) {
    if (typeof val1[i] === "object") {
      deeplyEquals(JSON.stringify(val1[i]), JSON.stringify(val2[i]));
    } else if (typeof val2[i] === "object") {
      deeplyEquals(JSON.stringify(val1[i]), JSON.stringify(val2[i]));
    } else if (val1[i] !== val2[i]) {
      counter++;
    }
  }

  return counter === 0 ? true : false;
};
```

I implemented a counter so that if it found a value in 1 that was not equal to the same value in 2 then it would increment. If the counter was not 0 then it would return false.

For the example, the counter increments to 7 but then right at the end, changes to 0 and therefore returns true instead of false.
I'm sure there would be an easier way to do this but I was wanting to see whether I could make this work as I am unsure why the counter is changing to 0 right at the end.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why does this have to be a recursion?

Comment: You are using JSON stringily so why are you not just doing it from the start?  `JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)`

Comment: The question I am completing asks us to use recursion @B001ᛦ

Comment: Oh, understood, that's homework. Homework never use real-life cases and always require to do tings in a completely twisted way. Not sure that's how you train good programmers though.

Comment: Well if you are doing recursion than sending a string back to deeplyEquals does not make sense.  You need to loop over the object keys and see if all the keys match and that all the values are the same. If the value is an array or an object, you got more recursion to do.

Comment: @JeremyThille I completely agree, there are much easier ways to do it!

Comment: @epascarello you are correct, I have changed it to use key-value pairs instead of sending a string back to deeplyEquals

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the counter is **local** to each call to `deeplyEquals`. There's a **different** `counter` for each call, and since you're making the calls recursively, you have lots of different `counter` variables in memory at the same time.

If you wanted to maintain a `counter`, you'd have to have each recursive call return the counter value (instead of a flag) so the code calling it could increment its counter by that much.

But there's no need in your code. Instead, just `return false` the first time you find a difference, either during in the call itself or in one of its recursive calls by checking the return value of the recursive call.

---

There are other issues with the code. Here's what I notice off-the-cuff:

- You're calling `JSON.stringify`, which returns a string, before passing values to `deeplyEquals`, which will convert arrays and objects to strings. Comparing the strings won't be reliable (because equivalent objects can have their properties in different orders: `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2})` is the string `{"a":1,"b":2}`, but `JSON.stringify({b:2,a:1})` is the string `{"b":2,"a":1}`). Instead, pass the actual value.
- `typeof x` returns `"object"` for arrays and `null` as well as non-array objects; you need to handle those three cases separately.
- When comparing non-array objects, you need to loop through their properties to compare them.

SO has several questions and answers about doing deep equality checks; probably best to search for those, study them to ensure you understand how they work, and go from there.

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions and help. I think I'm trying to make something work that is more complicated than starting again and doing it differently. I will look into your comments, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just JSON stringify both arrays and then compare?

```
const deepEquals(val1, val2){
    let v1 = JSON.stringify(val1);
    let v2 = JSON.stringify(val2);

    return v1 === v2;
}
```

Comment: This is unreliable by most definitions of "equality" of objects: 1. It's sensitive to the order of properties, but usually we consider `{a: 1, b: 2}` and `{b: 2, a: 1}` to be equivalent. 2. It completely disregards properties with the value `undefined` or referring to functions, considering `{a: undefined}` and `{a: function() {}  }`, and `{}` to all be equivalent. 3. It fails for cyclic relationships (because `JSON.stringify` can't create JSON for cyclic relationships).